# WooCommerce added_to_cart delegated event in single product pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, when I click on add to cart button in single product pages, the product is added to cart successfully. Now, once the product is added to cart (after page is reloaded) I would like to trigger the display for **CHECKOUT** and **SEE CART** buttons pop in box.

The following code work fine on **AJAX ADD TO CART** but not for **SINGLE ADD TO CART** as it's not ajax enabled:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
    console.log('added_to_cart');
});
```

How could I make it work for non **SINGLE ADD TO CART**?

Ajax add to cart ***(work)***: https://test.sushi2500.dk/takeaway/nigiri-laks/ 
Single add to cart ***(doesn't work)***: https://test.sushi2500.dk/takeaway/maanedstilbud/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Nov 2020**

- *Check cart items to be sure the product has been added to cart*.
- *Handling more product data, product variations and their attributes*.

On single product page, as the data is submitted on a form using **"post" method** *(no JS / AJAX involved)*, So you can detect "added to cart" event using the PHP **`$_POST`** variables, this way:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'single_added_to_cart_event');
function single_added_to_cart_event()
{
    if( isset($_POST['add-to-cart']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) ) :

    // Get added to cart product ID (or variation ID) and quantity (if needed)
    $id_to_check   = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? esc_attr($_POST['variation_id']) : esc_attr($_POST['add-to-cart']);
    $product_id   = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? esc_attr($_POST['variation_id']) : esc_attr($_POST['add-to-cart']);
    $variation_id  = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? esc_attr($_POST['variation_id']) : 0;
    $quantity      = esc_attr($_POST['quantity']);
    $found_in_cart = false; // Initializing

    // Check cart items to be sure that the product has been added to cart (and get product data)
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $product = $item['data']; // The WC_Product Object
        if( $product->get_id() == $id_to_check ) {
            $product_name = $product->get_name(); // Product name
            $sku          = $product->get_sku(); // Product sku
            $type         = $product->get_type(); // Product sku
            $price        = wc_get_price_to_display($product); // Product price for display
            $stock_qty    = $product->get_stock_quantity(); // Product sku
            $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status(); // Product sku
            $attributes   = $variation_id > 0 ? json_encode($product->get_attributes()) : "''";

            $found_in_cart = true;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }


    if( $found_in_cart ) :

    // The displayed message (example)
    if ( $variation_id > 0 ) {
        $message = sprintf( __('Product "%s" has been added to cart. \r\nProduct type: %s \r\nProduct price: %s \r\nProduct_id: %s \r\nVariation_id: %s \r\nQuantity: %s'),
            $product_name, $type, $price, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity );
    } else {
        $message = sprintf( __('Product "%s" has been added to cart. \r\nProduct type: %s \r\nProduct price: %s \r\nProduct_id: %s \r\nQuantity: %s'),
            $product_name, $type, $price, $product_id, $quantity );
    }

    // JS code goes here below
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // All product data
        var product_id   = <?php echo esc_attr($_POST['add-to-cart']); ?>,
            variation_id = <?php echo $variation_id; ?>,
            quantity     = <?php echo $quantity; ?>,
            attributes   = <?php echo $attributes; ?>,
            name         = '<?php echo $product_name; ?>',
            type         = '<?php echo $type; ?>',
            sku          = '<?php echo $sku; ?>',
            price        = '<?php echo $price; ?>',
            stock_qty    = '<?php echo $stock_qty; ?>',
            stock_status = '<?php echo $stock_status; ?>',
            message      = '<?php echo $message; ?>';

        console.log(message);
        if ( variation_id > 0 ) console.log(attributes);

        alert(message);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif; endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and work for single product pages *(or if using `[product_page id="99"]` shortcode like )*.

[image]

You can use the code on a template, on a custom function *(or in a custom shortcode)*.

Comment: where do i add this code. when i add this snippets to function.php it causing 403 forbidden error.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it's going to fire the `added_to_cart` event even if the product doesn't get validated on `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco I have updated my code to handle `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook when a product is not validated or not added to cart for some other reasons… As you will see, now I check cart items to be sure that the product is added to cart. Now your code answer doesn't really answer the OP question as triggering **Ajax** "added_to_cart" event will give an event with empty product parameters… Remember that  "added_to_cart" event is for Ajax add to cart and this event allow to get some product parameters that will be empty when triggering as you are doing…

Comment: Great @LoicTheAztec , thanks for the update. Regarding my code, you're right. It doesn't have product parameters right now, but I think I'd be able to do it be getting the product parameters from the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco Sorry but your answer code still doesn't handle added to cart product variations as it doesn't give the variation Id and the related attributes… As I have said before, "added_to_cart" event is just for Ajax add to cart and simple products, but not all other product types that requires normal add to cart on single product page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document.body ).on( '.wc-variation-selection-needed', function(){

      console.log('added_to_cart');

});
```

Try this

Comment: This is just a console.log. How should this solve the problem lol?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Triggering is not working, that's the issue right? :)

Comment: Yes you can check both link then you understand more clearly

Comment: @Viveksaroch Both not logging in Google Chrome :)

Answer (score 0):

With this approach I believe you'll be able to trigger the `added_to_cart` event on single pages just fine, avoiding the issue of triggering it unintentionally if the product has not been added to cart in case it hasn't been validated on the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter for example.

You can pass any other arguments to the event from the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook, like product id, quantity, variation id, etc.

If the `added_to_cart` event is not appropriate for you you can fire your own custom event if you wish.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'trigger_single_added_to_cart_event', 10, 6 );
function trigger_added_to_cart_event_in_single_product_page() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    add_action( 'wp_footer', function () use( $params ) {
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $(document.body).trigger({
                    type: 'added_to_cart',
                    product_id:<?php echo esc_attr( $params[1] ) ?>,
                    quantity:<?php echo esc_attr( $params[2] ) ?>
                });
            }); 
        </script>
        <?php
    } );
}
```

Comment: The "added_to_cart" event is just for Ajax add to cart, so not for single product pages! So the "added_to_cart" triggered by your code will be empty, no product id set in it (no data related)…

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, I believe it won't be empty anymore

Comment: This will not work when adding to cart product variations, as the event "added_to_cart" doesn't handle product variations and their attributes…